# Windows Store App crash dump analysis

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-store-apps, windbg, crash-dumps

I downloaded the Windows Store App crash logs and I got a .cab file which I decoded with the help of windbg. But the issue is that I don't know how to analyse these logs.

```
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

PROCESS_NAME:  backgroundTaskHost.exe
ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xe0434352 - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xe0434352 - <Unable to get error code text>

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  backgroundtaskhost.exe!unknown_error_in_process

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: backgroundtaskhost

IMAGE_NAME:  backgroundtaskhost.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5010a827

STACK_COMMAND:  !pe cd15a99100
 ; ** Pseudo Context ** ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS_e0434352_backgroundtaskhost.exe!unknown_error_in_process

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS_CLR_EXCEPTION_backgroundtaskhost.exe!unknown_error_in_process

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:wrong_symbols_e0434352_backgroundtaskhost.exe!unknown_error_in_process

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {b7904d12-3545-f92a-82d7-4be5db344ea7}

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Comment: It is trying *very* hard to tell you that it doesn't have the right symbol files to tell you what went wrong.  That's a mistake that every programmer makes once, everybody always forgets to preserve the PDB files after building the Release build and submitting their app to the Store.  Lesson learned.

Comment: Parsing error logs is never an easy read. More like a mine field of riddles... :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the version of the symbols (pdb files) of your app as it was published to the store. Then you might also need to reference these in windbg - with the [`.symfix`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565400(v=vs.85).aspx) command perhaps?